# why can not use strlen(char[]) to compare a value

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char words[2][3] = {{'a','b','c'},{'A','B','C'}};

        for(int j= 0 ;j < 2;j++){

            long diff =   0 - (strlen(words[j]));

            printf("%d , %d \n"  ,  (diff <= 0)  ,  (0  -  strlen(words[j]) <= 0 )  );

        }

    return 0;
}
```

/*

1 , 0

1 , 0

*/

why ? I expected result is  1,1  .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cll09.png)

Comment: In a nut shell, because `words[i]` is not a (zero-terminated) string. It’s just an array of characters.

Comment: is `0  -  strlen(words[j]) <= 0` evaluated as `(0  -  strlen(words[j])) <= 0` or `0  -  (strlen(words[j]) <= 0)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strlen` expects a pointer to a string. A "string" in C is a **zero terminated** array of characters.

Neither `{'a','b','c'}` nor `{'A','B','C'}` arrays are zero terminated. So calling `strlen` on them is undefined behavior.

You need to put a terminating zero character `'\0'` (or just `0` for byte strings) after the array that compose the string. So to make execution of your program defined, you have to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    char words[2][4] = { // note - include space for zero in size.
        // equal to "abc"
        {'a','b','c','\0'},
        // string literal can be used as initializers too
        // and they are zero teminated
        "ABC"
    };
    for(int j= 0 ;j < 2;j++){
        long diff =   0 - (strlen(words[j]));
        printf("%d , %d \n"  ,  (diff <= 0)  ,  (0  -  strlen(words[j]) <= 0 )  );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> why diff <= 0 and (0 - strlen(words[j]) <= 0 ) is diffrent ?

Because `strlen` returns an unsigned type `size_t`, the expression `0 - strlen(words[j])` has unsigned type, so it can't be negative. On substraction from zero unsigned underflow happens and it results in a very big unsigned value.

`diff` has type `long`, so it is signed. On `diff` initialization `diff =   0 - (strlen(words[j]));` the unsigned result of `0 - (strlen(words[j]))` is converted to type `long` which results in a small negative signed value (on your machine).